# Authentication using Azure AAD

Tags: azure, authentication

I am developing a banking application on Azure platform. Initially we started with B2C as identity provider however B2C does not integrate with office 365 so now thinking of moving with Azure AAD as identity provider.

Is it safe to onboard external clients on Azure AAD and authenticate users and give single sign-on on office 365 as well ?

Please let me know your thought on this or any recommendation.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: If you only want to provide SSO for document collaboration via OneDrive, you might be better to centralise documents within your infrastructure which you expose via an API or app secured with B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Safe as in secure? Yes, I don't believe Azure AD is fundamentally any less secure than B2C.

Couple of things you might want to consider:

- Azure AD is much more expensive than Azure AD B2C.

10,000 AD users, per month: ~$10,000,00 on basic tier, ~$60,000,00 on Premium 1, and ~$90,000,00 on Premium 2.

B2C is billed on number of authentications; and you get 50,000 free authentications a month, this would the equivalent of 10,000 users signing in 5 times each.

- You might need to setup B2B is you want to provide access to external user identities.
- Azure AD has a wider range of features you may need to manage.
- B2C is designed explicity for business to consumer. Azure AD with B2B is business to business.

Comment: Thanks James for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have left a few things out.

What is your SSO strategy (B2B or a custom model)?
What Office 365 applications do you want Users to have access to?

Comment: SSO strategy I need help here. It’s banking application. Office 365 is for one drive  for document collaboration

Comment: What is the business requirement you are trying to fulfil? I'm asking this because you can separate the technical solution from the requirement itself. If you need to provide SSO with access to SharePoint files, my next question would be who are these Third Parties? Customers or Partners? Either way, you will need to look at B2B in this case.

Comment: Thanks Syed. We are going with B2B approach.

Answer (score 0):

The identity provider that you use has more to do with who your user is than anything else. For example, if you are a retail bank providing services to individuals then you'll probably want to use AAD B2C since its really a consumer scenario. If you are building an application for employees of the bank, then you'll want to use AAD.

If you are a bank that provides a service to commercial clients then you might want to consider delivering a multi-tenant AAD application where your customers add your banking platform as a SaaS application to their directory (scenario being that you can integrate directly with their directory for controlling access to accounts, approval workflows etc).

AAD B2B is primarily when you want to invite external users into your own internal systems as a guest (different to a multi-tenant SaaS application).